# Best data structure for an N-ary tree

Tags: c++, c++11, tree, artificial-intelligence, chess

I need to represent a tree with multiple branches per node. What structure should I use? It's for computing chess game states. It explodes exponentially so memory will be a concern. I'm using C++11 but am open to other standards. Also, pruning should be O(1).

EDIT1
To expand, I am going to be holding a Chess AI competition. The main PvP game is complete already, and I am programming the AI API next. Contestants will write their own AI, and then we will have them compete in a tournament. The winner's AI will be used in Player vs Computer games. I am just thinking about the best structure to store my game states and AI thoughts.

I was reading up on Deep Blue, and it thinks from 5 to ~25 moves ahead. I can imagine most computers capable of handling 5 moves deep with BFS, but anything deeper and I believe I will have to use DFS.

AI's will be timed, and competing AI's will only be played locally, so as not to introduce advantages in CPU power.

I am reading up on Monte Carlo and Alpha Beta searches now.

My initial thoughts on a data structure are as follows :

```
union CHESS_MOVE {
   unsigned short m;
   ChessPosT pos[2];
   ///...
};

class ChessMoveNode {
   CHESS_MOVE move;
   std::set<ChessMoveNode> nextmoves;
};

class ChessMoveTree {
   std::set<ChessMoveNode> next;
};
```

The board can be calculated at any time by concatenating the path from the root to the leaf. Although recalculating the board could get very expensive over time. Ideas? Should I store the board? The board is stored as an array of 64 char indices holding a piece number. So it's 16 bytes, compared to 2, but the memory use would save a lot of re-calculation of the board state.

For my own personal AI, I will be implementing a board scoring function that will rank the game states, and then all non maximal game states will be discarded, as well as pruning game states that are invalidated by choosing a move.

Comment: O(1) for what? number of total nodes? depth?

Comment: If you are doing something like alpha-beta search, you shouldn't be storing the tree explicitly. Such algorithms use a DFS to avoid storing the tree. If you are using MCTS, the story is a bit different. Clarifying what algorithm you want to implement will help answer the question.

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher For removing all non chosen branches during game play.

Comment: "*It's for computing chess game states. It explodes exponentially so memory will be a concern*" - correct. As of right now, it's impossible for any device to store the data required to represent every possible chess scenario. You need to find another approach or to introduce the depth of your tree.

Comment: @Fureeish I'm storing a single move in an unsigned short. Each char stores a row and column packed in 4 signed bits each. I can store a very large number of nodes this way.

Comment: @BugSquasher the number of possible chess games is 10^120. The number of atoms in the observable universe is ~10^80. Even if you somehow used a single bit to represent a move or a board state, you are out of luck.

Comment: @Fureeish and each move played prunes roughly 90% of the .

Comment: First, the *90%* part is incorrect. Second, even if it was, that would still be impossible.

Comment: @Fureeish, not it's not incorrect. Each move played prunes (N-1)/N percent of the tree. I'm not trying to calculate every single possibility. That is an assumption you made.

Comment: Then you provided too little information. What was your attempt? What has failed?

Comment: I have edited the post to be more thorough in my explanation of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach to do this that works well for Monte-Carlo Tree Search (MCTS) is to use a `vector` of some custom class. Inside the class you have whatever state information you need in addition to child information -- the number of the children and their index in the vector. This avoids storing a separate pointer for each child, which can introduce significant overhead.

So, the root is at index `0`. Inside that index there would be two integers indicating that the children start at index `1` and that there are `k` children. (From index `1` to `k`.) At index `1` the children would start at index `k+1` with `l` total children, and so on throughout the tree.

This works really well based on the assumptions that (1) the number of children is fixed, (2) that they are all added at once, and (3) that states are not removed from the tree.

If you are trying to prune states from the tree, this doesn't work as well, because you will leave gaps in tree if you remove them. Using explicit pointers for storing each child is expensive, so something else is done in practice.

First, with alpha-beta search you typically search the tree with a DFS and don't store branches. But, you use a hash table to store states and check for duplicates. The branches of the tree can be implicitly computed from the state, so you can reconstruct the tree without storing everything explicitly.

Note, however, that hash tables (called transposition tables in the context of game tree search) are not typically used deep in the tree because there are many states and the cost of storing grows while the benefit of removing duplicates shrinks.

**To summarize**, based on the assumption that you are doing something alpha-beta like and you have a good reason to store the tree explicitly, I suggest store the states in a hash table and leave the edges to be implicitly computed from a move-generation function. (Which would apply moves and take the hash of the resulting state to find them in the hash table. If they aren't there they have been pruned.)

Comment: I will look up Monte Carlo Tree Search

Comment: A hash of the state would be much larger than a single unsigned short holding the move. Memory use is a concern. I also have to score the board for each position, and the max score is only known once a whole level has been searched, as later positions can greatly increase the value of lower nodes if they lead to checkmate. I'm still not sure what to do. What do you think of my edit?

Comment: @BugSquasher I think you're in a bit over your head. First get something working and then work on optimizing the memory. Read up more on game tree search techniques - there is a massive amount of work that has been done on this topic. For your AI either go the alpha-beta route, in which case you don't store the tree at all, but use transposition tables, or go the alpha-zero route and use MCTS.

Comment: 30^5 is only 20million or so. The tree could be fully explored 5 deep and then I was planning on the MCTS

Comment: @BugSquasher The method described works well for MCTS - it is how I've implemented MCTS personally.